# How to solve matrix to the power of n equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This type of equation surely has to have a name and a resolution strategy:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & B \\[] C & D \end{array}\right)^n \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\[] b \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\[] b \end{array}\right)$$

The goal is to determine the integer $n$ where this is fulfilled.

I only can think of diagonalizing the matrix and starting from there. I'm not asking for a complete Solution, giving me some links is far enough.

Comment: Do you have any data about the matrices, does it have to be fulfilled by each vectors ? Are the elements in your matrix matrices or scalars (if they are scalars, don’t use capital letters) otherwise unless your matrix is idempotent, the valid answer is $n=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unitary rotation and reflection matrices have this property. Assume without loss of generality that your matrix is either $M=RF$ or $M=R$ where $R$ is a rotation (arbitrary angle $\theta$) and F is a reflection (arbitrary axis of $\phi/2$ degrees from the x-axis (could choose $\phi$ degrees but that would give $2\phi$ in the trig)).
$$R = \left(\begin{matrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{matrix}\right)$$
$$F = \left(\begin{matrix}\cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ \sin(\phi) & -\cos(\phi) \end{matrix}\right)$$

without loss of generality, $M$ can be decomposed to either $RF$ or $R$. For the $M = RF$,
$$\begin{align}M & =RF \\
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) & \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)-\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
\end{matrix}\right) \\
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta+\phi) & \sin(\theta+\phi) \\
\sin(\theta+\phi) & -\cos(\theta+\phi) \\
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}$$

which is actually just a new reflection matrix $F_{\theta+\phi}$

so, $M = F$ (some reflection matrix) or $M = R$ (some rotation matrix). Obviously for reflection matrices, $n = 2m$, $m\in\mathbb Z$. For rotations, $2k\pi=n\theta$ so $n = k\frac{2\pi}{\cos^{-1}(A)}= k\frac{2\pi}{\theta}$ which ostensibly requires $\frac{2\pi}{\theta} \in \mathbb Q$, otherwise we're talking about non-integer exponentiation.

Lets look at the equation again and say $R^n \vec v = R_{n\theta}\vec v = \vec v$

Then,
$$(R_{n\theta}-I)\vec v=0$$
so, $$\begin{align} \det(R_{n\theta}-I)&=0\\
(\cos(n\theta)-1)^2+\sin^2(n\theta) & = 0\\
-2\cos(n\theta)+2&=0\\
n &= \frac{1}{\theta}\cos^{-1}\left(1\right) \\
&= \frac{2k\pi}{\theta}\end{align}$$

once again.

If we're looking for a positive integer $n$, we require $\theta = \frac{2k\pi}{p}$, where $k$ is the "winding number", $p$ is any nonzero integer.

Basically, the matrix has to be a reflection or a rotation with $\theta = \frac{2k\pi}{p}$, otherwise $n=0$ is the only solution. On the contrary if one of these conditions is satisfied there are countably infinite solutions.
For the smallest positive integer $n$, we require $\theta=\frac{2k\pi}{p}$, where $k$ and $p$ are coprime, such that $n=p$.

Anyway, hopefully this gives you enough to get your head around it, the point is for nearly all matrices $n=0$ is the only soln and the only solvable cases are the reflections and rotations, with reflections or "$\pi$-rational" rotations required to solve integer $n$.

Comment: Sorry for replying that late, I had my head in other thing, but your wonderful explanations clear my main questions in this area, thanks!